# Getting all unique pairs without GROUP BY

Tags: 8, database

I have table with the following structure:

```
id | sender_mail | recipient_mail | username | subject | message | created
1    aa@test.com    bb@test.com        aaa       xxxx     yyy       10
2    bb@test.com    aa@test.com        bbb       xxxx     yyy       11
3    cc@test.com    bb@test.com        ccc       xxxx     yyy       12
4    bb@test.com    cc@test.com        bbb       xxxx     yyy       13
5    dd@test.com    gg@test.com        ddd       xxxx     yyy       14
6    gg@test.com    bb@test.com        ggg       xxxx     yyy       15
```

What I want is to get all unique pairs between columns sender_mail and recipient_mail where one of those columns has a value of email I'm passing in to the query. For example, if i put in **bb@test.com** as argument, the desired output should be:

```
id | sender_mail | recipient_mail | username | subject | message | created
2    bb@test.com    aa@test.com        bbb       xxxx     yyy       11
4    bb@test.com    cc@test.com        bbb       xxxx     yyy       13
6    gg@test.com    bb@test.com        ggg       xxxx     yyy       15
```

I tried out this SQL query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM messages AS m
WHERE
    m.sender_mail = 'bb@test.com' OR
    m.recipient_mail = 'bb@test.com'

GROUP BY m.sender_mail, m.recipient_mail
```

It seemed to work when I passed the query to database directly (sequel pro). But when I put this code in a Drupal controller, an error gets thrown out:

> Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[42000]: 
>   Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'drupal.m.username' isn't in
>   GROUP BY:  SELECT m.sender_mail, m.recipient_mail, m. username,
>   m.subject, m.message, m.created

After googling, I found out that Drupal 8 enforces ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY for SQL.

What is the workaround for this? How do I need to alter my query?

Comment: See the the referenced question that I marked this as a duplicate of. In short, Mysql doesn't know what value to pick from the username column when you don't group by it. If it's always the same, then it's easy, just group by it as well. If it's not and you just want to see any of the values, the referenced question links to a function you can use for that in the comments.